# How to use 'having' with paginate on relationship's column in laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to grab the vehicles whose relation 'dealer' is having distance < 200

```
Vehicle::join('dealers', 'vehicles.dealer_id', '=', 'dealers.id')
     ->select(DB::raw("dealers.id, ( cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) ) ) AS distance"))
     ->havingRaw('distance < 200');
```

I am trying to use havingRaw on the alias 'distance' from the relation (belongsTo) dealer. But failed with an error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'having clause'

**UPDATE**

The issue actually occurs when I add paginate function to the above query like this.

```
$vehicle = Vehicle::join('dealers', 'vehicles.dealer_id', '=', 'dealers.id')
 ->select(DB::raw("dealers.id, ( cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) ) ) AS distance"))
 ->havingRaw('distance < 200');

$result = $vehicle->paginate(15);
```

Comment: What is result of your ->havingRaw('distance < 200')->toSql() ?

Answer (score 7):

#### Update

If you use `paginate()` with your query laravel will try to execute the following SQL code to count the total number of possible matches:

```
select count(*) as aggregate 
from `vehicles` inner join `dealers` 
  on `vehicles`.`dealer_id` = `dealers`.`id`
having distance < 200
```

As you can see, there is no such column or alias `distance` in this query.

*Option 2* in my original answer will fix that issue too.

#### Original answer

That seams to be a MySQL-strict-mode issue. If you use laravel 5.3 strict mode is enabled per default. You have two options:

Option 1: Disable strict mode for MySQL in `config/database.php`

```
...
'mysql' => [
    ...
    'strict' => false,
    ...
],
...
```

Option 2: Use a WHERE condtition

```
Vehicle::join('dealers', 'vehicles.dealer_id', '=', 'dealers.id')
     ->select(DB::raw("dealers.id, ( cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) ) ) AS distance"))
     ->whereRaw('cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) ) < 200');
```

Documentation:

> A MySQL extension to standard SQL permits references in the HAVING
> clause to aliased expressions in the select list. Enabling
> ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY disables this extension, thus requiring the HAVING
> clause to be written using unaliased expressions.

[Server SQL Modes - ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

Comment: JFI - This query will run the logic twice so, there can be some performance issue.

Comment: @Amit - That might be an issue, but it probably won't. If you have a table with 1000 items (vehicles) and you use `LIMIT 20` (`paginate(20)`) the "logic" will be evaluated 1000 times in the WHERE clause and 20 times in the SELECT clause. That would be a relative overhead of 2% (in worst case). the bigger the table, the lesser the relative overhead. For smaller tables it doesn't matter because of the very low absolute runtime. IMHO the bigger problem is *code duplication*, which can be solved using a PHP variable.

Comment: Still, this doesn't solve the issue of using a having and pagination

Comment: @ArunP - It solves the problem behind the question. Laravels pagination doesn't (or at least didn't) work (well) with the HAVING clause.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I appreciates your answer but in some case it is not working. I do some research and found that Laravel has fixed this but in its [version 7](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/7.x). Here is the Ref https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/32624

Answer (score 3):

*Answer Updated corresponding to updated question*

The problem is with the query builder as all selects are discarded when doing an aggregate call (like count(*)). The make-do solution, for now, is to construct the paginator manually as:

```
$query = Vehicle::join('dealers', 'vehicles.dealer_id', '=', 'dealers.id')
             ->select(DB::raw("dealers.id, ( cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) ) ) AS distance"))
             ->having('distance', '<', '200');

$perPage = 10;
$curPage = \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::resolveCurrentPage();

$itemQuery = clone $query;

$items = $itemQuery->forPage($curPage, $perPage)->get();

$totalResult = $query->addSelect(DB::raw('count(*) as count'))->get();
$totalItems = $totalResult->first()->count;

$vehicles = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($items->all(), $totalItems, $perPage);
```

Comment: Logically the HAVING clause is executed after the SELECT clause. `count(*)` will be calculated without any condition. `distance` will be calculated for a "random" row because nonaggregated columns are used. After that the HAVING condition will be checked for that "random" distance. So you will either get the count of all rows without the distance condition or you won't get a count at all.

Comment: $totalItems = $totalResult->count(); I think this better to get totalcount

Answer (score 2):

`having` and `havingRaw` doesn't have access to generated fields in the query
see this example from laravel docs
[image]

Your query will have to lookk like this

```
Vehicle::join('dealers', 'vehicles.dealer_id', '=', 'dealers.id')
            ->select(DB::raw("dealers.id, ( cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) ) ) AS distance"))
            ->havingRaw('(cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude))) < 200');
```

Comment: you are genius you save my day :). Thanks a lot

Comment: This looks like the exact solution I need but in my case the latitude and longitude columns are in a join table which havingRaw also seems not to be able to access. 

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Here's something I did that appears to be similar to what you're trying to do:

```
public function scopeNearest($query, Geo $geo, $miles = 25)
{
    return $query
        ->select(DB::raw("*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians({$geo->lat}) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians({$geo->lng}) ) + sin( radians({$geo->lat}) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance"))
        ->groupBy('id')
        ->having('distance', '<', $miles)
        ->orderBy('distance');
}
```

In this example, I had a separate model handling latitude and longitude coordinates, as well as address information called `Geo`. You might not need that level of separation, so you can probably refactor to something like this:

```
public function scopeNearest($query, $lat, $lng, $miles = 25)
{
    return $query
        ->select(DB::raw("*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians({$lat}) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians({$lng}) ) + sin( radians({$lat}) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance"))
        ->groupBy('id')
        ->having('distance', '<', $miles)
        ->orderBy('distance');
}
```

Remember, in order to calculate distance, you need two points. The model will be able to check the distance between two points by using its own `latitude` and `longitude` columns against the latitude and longitude provided to the scope query as an argument.

You can put this in your Vehicle model and call like so:

```
Vehicle::nearest($latitude, $longitude, 200);
```

This is untested for your use-case, so I can't guarantee that it will work out of the box, but hopefully it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I am actually having issue when using join along with 'having'

Comment: The latitude and longitude is not stored in vehicle model, but its in relationship model called dealer.

Comment: Are you able to make this work with Laravel's pagination?

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
Vehicle::join('dealers', 'vehicles.dealer_id', '=', 'dealers.id')
 ->select(DB::raw("dealers.id, ( cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) ) ) AS distance")->havingRaw('distance < 200'));
```