# How to use paginate in this query laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

How to use pagination for this query ?

```
$listings = DB::table('listings')
                ->selectRaw('*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(' . $lat . ') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(' . $lng . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $lat .') ) * sin( radians(latitude) ) ) ) AS distance')
                ->having('distance', '<', $distance)
                ->orderBy('distance')->paginate(10);
```

I tried paginate(10) it doesnt work.

the error : 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `listings` having `distance` < 5)

Comment: I'm not so sure for this. But, you can try it. `'*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(' . $lat . ') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(' . $lng . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $lat .') ) * sin( radians(latitude) ) ) ) AS distance' having distance < ' . $distance` and remove `->having('distance', '<', $distance)`

Comment: Try this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194120/how-to-use-having-with-paginate-on-relationships-column-in-laravel-5 Hope you will get solution

Answer (score 1):

`$distance` must be a variable and it should have the value had you passed the value for `$distance` 
it should be like

```
$listings = DB::table('listings')
            ->selectRaw('*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(' . $lat . ') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(' . $lng . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $lat .') ) * sin( radians(latitude) ) ) ) AS distance')
           ->having('distance', '<', 100)
           ->orderBy('distance')
           ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: I don't think that this is not a solution for this. The problem is laravel query doesn't recognize distance alias name.