# Query builder error while using both having and paginate method

Tags: laravel-5

I have used having and paginate in a query builder in Laravel 5.4.But its showing error.If i removed paginate method it is working properly.Here is my code

```
DB::table('nearbies')
    ->select(DB::raw('( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians(9.955308) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(76.302331) )+ sin ( radians(9.955308) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ))) AS distance,id,name,location'))
    ->havingRaw('( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians(9.955308) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(76.302331) )+ sin ( radians(9.955308) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ))) < 10')
    ->orderBy('distance','asc')
    ->paginate(3);
```

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'latitude' in 'having clause'

Comment: try whereRaw instead of havingRaw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

havingRaw does not have access to generated field. You therefore need to use whereRaw instead of havingRaw, as explained in this answer : 
[How to use 'having' with paginate on relationship's column in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194120/how-to-use-having-with-paginate-on-relationships-column-in-laravel-5)