# Pagination shows error when use having in query builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a query like the following, and it works as expected. I used here the `havingRaw` option to filter the result.

```php
$customers = Customer::select(DB::raw("`name`, `mobile`, `branch`, count(*) as total_orders"))
    ->groupBy('mobile')
    ->havingRaw('total_orders > 12')
    ->orderBy('total_orders', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

As the total number of returned row will vary, i need to show it as paginated. So i changed the query like below. Then it shows error that the `total_orders` column not found.

```php
$customers = Customer::select(DB::raw("`name`, `mobile`, `branch`, count(*) as total_orders"))
    ->groupBy('mobile')
    ->havingRaw('total_orders > 12')
    ->orderBy('total_orders', 'desc')
    ->paginate();
```

I found some workarounds for the previous versions of Laravel. I am using Laravel 5.6 for my project, is there any solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use 'having' with paginate on relationship's column in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194120/how-to-use-having-with-paginate-on-relationships-column-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$customers = Customer::select(DB::raw("`name`, `mobile`, `branch`, count(*) as 
  total_orders"))
 ->groupBy('mobile')
 ->having('total_orders','>', 12)
 ->orderBy('total_orders', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: i updated the question, i was facing issue with `paginate()`

Comment: column not found error getting in orderBy or Having ?

Comment: `having` is alright for `get()` but not working for `paginate()`